# PerformClick does not execute if placed after Show()

Tags: c#

I have a windows form with an invisible button and a progressbar. I would like a menuitem to instantiate the form and trigger the click.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
        button1.PerformClick();

    }
```

If I place the Show() as above, PerformClick doesn't execute, which sort of makes sense.
If I place the Show() AFTER the PerformClick, the PerformClick executes but the form with the progressbar doesn't show until all the code of PerformClick has executed. So I get no progressbar showing the progress until all is complete. This also makese sense. So how do I get PerformClick to work AND have the form with the progressbar showing progress both at the same time?

thanks

Comment: take a look at background worker

Comment: Show() has no effect whatsoever, it was already called.  That's what got the form loaded.  Use the Shown event instead.  Call this.Update() and then do whatever gets your UI to hang up.  Get ahead by using BackgroundWorker instead.